# SQL - JOIN statement creating duplicate entries

Tags: mysql, sql, database, foreign-keys, primary-key

I am new to SQL and I am running into trouble.

I have 3 tables:

```
CREATE TABLE indexCodes 
{
   (indexNum VARCHAR(5) PRIMARY KEY, 
   courseString VARCHAR(10), 
   title VARCHAR(20)
}

CREATE TABLE userid
{
     (id  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT, 
     email VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
     password VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)
}

    CREATE TABLE snipes
{ 
      (snipeNumber  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT), 
       FOREIGN KEY indexNum REFERENCES indexcodes(indexNum),
       FOREIGN KEY userID REFERENCES userid(id)
}
```

Using the JOIN statement

```
SELECT  userid.id, userID.email, snipes.indexNum, indexcodes.courseString, == indexcodes.title
FROM userid JOIN
     snipes JOIN
     indexcodes ON indexcodes.indexNum = snipes.indexNum
```

I run into duplicate entries.
For example, an indexcode inserted based on one user shows an index for all users

Comment: *I run into duplicate entries.* Duplicates are the rows when the values of ALL columns in this rows are identical. If the value in at least one column differs then these rows are NOT duplicates. If duplicates are present in the output then at least one of the tables contains duplicated rows itself.

Answer (score 0):

Try using these 2 options

1. GROUP BY clause

   SELECT  userid.id, userID.email, snipes.indexNum, indexcodes.courseString, == indexcodes.title FROM userid JOIN snipes
   JOIN indexcodes ON indexcodes.indexNum = snipes.indexNum GROUP BY userid.id
2. DISTINCT

   SELECT  DISTINCT userid.id, userID.email, snipes.indexNum, indexcodes.courseString, == indexcodes.title FROM userid JOIN snipes
   JOIN indexcodes ON indexcodes.indexNum = snipes.indexNum

Answer (score 0):

MySQL is the only database that supports `JOIN` with no corresponding `ON` clause.  It should really return an error!

You are missing `JOIN` conditions:

```
SELECT userid.id, userID.email, snipes.indexNum, indexcodes.courseString, == indexcodes.title
FROM user
     snipes
     ON snipes.userid = user.id JOIN
     indexcodes
     ON indexcodes.indexNum = snipes.indexNum ;
```